# How can I use meta viewport and CSS media queries to make the average 960px website look good on the iPhone and iPad?

Tags: html, css, mobile

## Question

I know there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow about the meta viewport tag, but I can't find anyone asking what seems to be the most obvious and useful question:

**How can I use meta viewport and CSS media queries to make the average 960px website design look good on the iPad (and desktop), while still retaining a smaller viewport and site design (e.g., 320px) for the iPhone and other mobile phones?**

For the iPhone, I think it goes without saying: a smaller, phone-friendly site (e.g., 320px wide) is ideal. But for the iPad's larger screen, a special mobile site isn't really necessary; using the normal 960px site design seems appropriate. A 320px site looks clownish on the iPad, and I don't always want to design a third variation for the iPad's 768px.

Here's the problem: I can't figure out how to use the meta viewport tag and CSS media queries to achieve both **1) a normal site on the iPad, and 2) a mobile site on the iPhone**. I realize it's possible with JavaScript hacks (e.g., dynamically changing the meta viewport tag according to the device), but I don't want to use JavaScript; I don't think JS should be required to achieve basic usability on a simple website with static content.

1) If I remove the meta viewport tag altogether, my normal 960px site looks *perfect* on the iPad, but bad on the iPhone (large empty margin on the right side):

[image: Website example without meta viewport tag]

2) On the other hand, if I use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`, then the site looks great on the iPhone, but bad on the iPad (zoomed to 768px, site spills outside of the viewport):

[image: Website example with meta viewport tag]

This seems like it should be the simplest thing in the world, but I haven't been able to solve it. What am I missing?

## Markup/CSS

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { margin: 0; }
.mobile { width: 320px; background: #fdd; display: none; }
.desktop { width: 960px; background: #ddf; }
</style>

<style type="text/css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
.mobile { display: block; }
.desktop { display: none; }
</style>
```

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="mobile">Phone (320px)</div>
<div class="desktop">Desktop and tablet (960px)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

Combine a media query with `zoom`.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    html {zoom:0.8;}
}
```

Comment: Be careful using zoom. It's a non-validating, Microsoft-specific extension to CSS. Firefox doesn't appear to support it at present (though that may not matter for mobile websites).

Comment: This does not have the desired result, it squashes the content.

Comment: @Shaun Worked just fine for me.

Comment: Can anyone confirm the quality of this method vs changing the viewport width?

Comment: Works cross-browser: `transform: scale(1); -ms-transform:scale(1); /* IE 9 */ -webkit-transform:scale(1); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */ -moz-transform:scale(1); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */`

Answer (score 5):

Try adding maximum-scale to your meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use JS to rip out the meta viewport tags like Cole discusses here - http://cole007.net/blog/136/responsiveish-viewport-hack there's also another option in the comments

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution in my opinion. It would be even better if this answer contained a summary.

Answer (score 0):

I use Serban Ghita's php Mobile Detection method:

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

...then this php in the head tag:

```
<?php
if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {?>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, max-scale = 1.0">
<?php } ?>
```

Works great.

Comment: This might be effective but theoretically it’s pretty horrible to do such things on the server-side. Users should be able to save web documents and view them on different devices and still have it work as expected. Not that anyone would ever really do such a thing, but… y’know… Theoretically.