# Setting min-width of screen within media query, vs Viewport tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

What's the best way of simply 'shrinking' a site to fit on to an iPad, while making it fully responsive when it comes to mobiles?

Here's my viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

I had hoped that the following media query would enable the whole 1060px wrapper div to be displayed by forcing the device to 'zoom out' thus displaying all, like a mini version of the desktop display

```
#wrapper {
    background: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1060px;
}

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

        body { min-width: 1080px; }

        wrapper { background: red; }

    }
```

The media query itself works (wrapper background turns red on iPad), but I still need to zoom out to view the whole page.

However, if I change to my viewport tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080px">
```

I get the desired result, but this is no good since the mobile version needs to be fully responsive. So am hoping there's something I can add to the media query to achieve it.

Sure I'm missing something very obvious here - and seem to remember this technique working in the past - any help appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

It seems this has been raised before, same issue, and yet no solution:

[How can I use meta viewport and CSS media queries to make the average 960px website look good on the iPhone and iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939671/how-can-i-use-meta-viewport-and-css-media-queries-to-make-the-average-960px-webs)

Comment: Try adding the scale: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: No joy I'm afraid - page is still at same scale, this just stops any zooming.

Comment: Maybe the iPad simulates "wrong" values `device-width`. I know Windows Phone does simulate a smaller resolution (320px instead of 480px), since most mobile-optimized websites are not optimized for screens with such a high pixel density.

Comment: Your css doesn't make sense..You are saying when `max-device-width : 1024px` make `body { min-width: 1080px; }`

Comment: I'm with you there, re: the CSS not making sense - just hoped there was a reliable way to zoom out when on iPad, without using a hack on the viewport tag (like this one: http://cole007.net/blog/136/responsiveish-viewport-hack )

Comment: Here's my suggestion: for `(min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)` I would do percentage and shrink it in to fit the website in an ipad and tablet OR set min-width and do overflow visible, so you'll have scrolling(which is annoying for some people). Then below `768px` device - do percentage and shrink it further